# Trouble in understanding the result of $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{0}$ as shown on Wolfram Alpha

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, infinity

So in [wolfram alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUwR3.png) it says that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{0} = \infty^\sim$ where $\infty^\sim$ symbol is complex infinity.

I find it hard to understand this symbol and the concept, can someone please explain why this happens and why it is undefined.

Comment: From the [definition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexInfinity.html), `Complex infinity is an infinite number in the complex plane whose complex argument is unknown or undefined`

Comment: The fact that you can write a math formula (or enter one in Mathematica) does not imply that this formula has any meaning.

Comment: In the context of the extended complex plane $\overline{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ we have that $\frac{z}{0}=\infty$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, from which your limit follows. This assumes, however, that we are working in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$

Comment: Slightly related in that it also brings up the "complex infinity" that Wolfram Language team made up: [my answer to "Is $\infty+ i\times \infty$: $\tilde{\infty}$?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2122523/26369).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because we do not know how dividing by 0 looks like and it is simply not defined. You may argue $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{x}$ is the same form as you stated. But that is untrue because in your case, we have the fraction a type of $\frac{\rightarrow 0}{exact \;0}$ which is as good as dividing 2 by 0, because in the end $\rightarrow 0$ is still a finite number, just infinitesimally small. And as you do not know what the result of dividing by 0 is, we cannot predict what exactly the outcome may be, imaginary, real or complex